# how to call mysql procedure in php with php variable as arguments?

Tags: php, mysql, function, post, stored-procedures

i have defined the the mysql procedure as follows

```
    DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `create_subcategories`(IN path VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

insert ignore into moodleui.z_subcategories(name, idnumber, description, status, last_processed_date)
select distinct concat(path, subject), subject, subject, 0, now() from moodleui.timetable_instructor;
-- where concat(path, subject) not in (select name from moodleui.z_subcategories);


END
```

Now i want to call this procedure using php. Also i want to pass a php variable as an argument instead of contant string. I tried the following but it doesnt seem to work.
Please help me with this.

```
if(isset($_POST['path']))

{
$path=$_POST['path'];
echo $path;
mysql_query('CALL create_subcategories($path)');
}
```

Comment: Are you connected to the database? and what value is that function returning? Look for errors in that

Comment: Try `mysql_query("CALL create_subcategories('$path')");`, assuming $PATH is properly escaped (as it right now is not)

Comment: yes i am connected to database. if instead of $path i use constand string, its working fine.

Comment: thanks @EugenRieck .. works now.